# mostrar el momento de un logueo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en la que muestro los usuarios registrados en una pequeña web que tengo y en ella hay un campo que debería mostrar la fecha y la hora de la última vez que se hizo login con esa cuenta, pero en la bbdd de phpmyadmin aparece:

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

y en mi web esto otro:

> 30/11/-0001 12:00:00 am

El campo de la tabla donde llamo a la función lo lleno así:

```
<td><?php echo read_date($a_user['last_login']); ?></td>
```

Y la función read_date es esta:

```
function read_date($str){
        if($str){
            return date("d/m/Y h:m:s a",strtotime($str));
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Además, para actualizar esa fecha, tengo esta función:

```
function updateLastLogIn($user_id){
        global $db;
        $date=make_date();
        $sql="UPDATE users SET last_login='{$date}' WHERE id='{$user_id}' LIMIT 1";
        $result=$db->query($sql);
        return ($result&&$db->affected_rows()===1 ? true : false);
    }
```

Y la función make_date es esta:

```
function make_date(){
        return strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",time());
    }
```

¿Cómo puedo conseguir que me obtenga el momento del login y me lo muestre bien?

EDITO: el campo last_login es de tipo DATETIME y permite NULL.

Comment: Recordá que phpmyadmin es simplemente la herramienta que utilizás para visualizar tu base de datos (que probablemente es de MariaDB o MySQL), por lo tanto es irrelevante en la pregunta. Por otra parte: ¿tenés la certeza de que _read_date_ no está retornando `null`? ¿Imprimiste qué valor tiene `$date` antes de hacer el update? Por cierto, tu consulta parece vulnerable a inyecciones SQL. Procurá usar sentencias preparadas.

Comment: Hola Charly, ¿que tipo de dato almacena `last_login`? Por lo que comentas que muestra PPHMyAdmin, diría que es `DATETIME`, si es así, el problema es el formato que devuleve `make_date`. Por favor, presioná [edit] y agrega esta info en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el formato en el que estas tratando de guardar la fecha/hora en la columna `last_login`.

Si revisas [la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) dice:

> [...] El tipo `DATETIME` se utiliza para valores que contienen tanto partes de fecha como de hora. MySQL recupera y muestra valores `DATETIME` en formato `'AAAA-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'`. El rango soportado es de `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'` a `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'`.

Por otro lado, otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que la función [`strftime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)  desde `PHP 8.1.0` esta marcada como obsoleta y se desaconseja recurrir a esta función.

#### Solución:

Utilizar la función [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) y el formato (*equivalente al esperado*) que necesitas utilizar es `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

**Ejemplo**:

Podes crear otra función, por ejemplo:

```php
function make_db_datetime(){
    return date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
```

Y utilizarla para obtener la fecha en el formato correcto:

```php
function updateLastLogIn($user_id){
    global $db;
    $date = make_db_datetime();
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET last_login='{$date}' WHERE id='{$user_id}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    return ($result && $db->affected_rows() === 1 ? true : false);
}
```

---

**Recomendación:**

Te recomiendo configurar el [`--sql-mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode) de `MySQL` así:

```
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Esto lo podes hacer de muchas formas, por ejemplo:

- Modificar el `my.ini`o `my.cnf`
- Desde phpMyAdmin > Variables
- `SET GLOBAL` o `SET SESSION`

Podes encontrar más info en [la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos. Pero ahora me surge otro problema. La fecha aparece bien, y la hora en phpmyadmin también, pero no en la página web que marca unos 50 minutos menos.

Comment: Eso se debe a que la zona horaria (_timezone_) de `MySQL` es distinta al de `PHP`. Revisá [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34428563/3791844)